# Declaring a object public and then using it locally in F#

Tags: f#

I don't know much about F#  but i am working on a project (on C#) in which i have to make few changes inside pre-written  F# code.

I want to declare a object public and then use this object locally.(like we do in C#).

```
class abc
{
   public SubscriptionManager subman = null;  // object of class SubscriptionManager

   public void DoSomething()
   {
      subman = new SubscriptionManager();
   }
}
```

Something like this.

**Can i do this same thing into the F#?**

Comment: You aren't declaring any objects. `subman` is a field of `abc`. You can define classes and fields in F# too.

Comment: can you tell me how to do this in F#?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this?  Mutable public fields are not idiomatic in C#, nevermind F#.  If you explain more about the problem, I'm sure there is a better approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As people mentioned in the comments, there are a couple of reasons why this may not be the right thing to do. That being said, this code would give you roughly what you are after:

```
[<AllowNullLiteral>]
type Manager() = class end

type abc() = 
    member val subman: Manager = null with get, set
    member this.DoSomething() = this.subman <- Manager()
```

I've included a dummy `Manager` class just to make the thing compile. There's a related discussion about public fields also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24670719/public-mutable-field-in-object), that lists a solution where at least the mutable fields is not public.